# App crashes in Branch.io debug mode

Tags: android, branch.io

I installed Branch.io sdk in application but it keeps crashing once I enter debug mode.

Here is initialization:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this)
    ...
}
```

I successfully enter debug mode using 4 fingers like it is said in Branch.io documentation. However in a while (10-15sec) it starts posting a lot of post request to Branch.io resulting in app crash.

Here is post request sent when I enter debug mode:

```
Post value = {
"device_fingerprint_id": “xxxxx",
"device_name": "Nexus 7",
"os": "Android",
"os_version": 21,
"model": "Nexus 7",
"is_simulator": false,
"session_id": "186013940411551370",
"identity_id": "185720730762103937",
"sdk": "android1.9.0",
"retryNumber": 0,
"branch_key": “xxxxxxxx"
}
```

The response:

```
    returned {}
    ======= Connected to Branch Remote Debugger =======
```

After a while it starts firing events that results in app restart or even crash

```
Post value = {
"device_fingerprint_id": "xxxx",
"session_id": "186013940411551370",
"identity_id": "185720730762103937",
"log": "BranchSDK\tposting to https:\/\/api.branch.io\/v1\/debug\/log",
"sdk": "android1.9.0",
"retryNumber": 0,
"branch_key": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Could you post a stack trace here?

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a variety of reasons. Branch recently discovered that if a request was sent and the response was malformed, it could expose an NPE. More information here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/pull/155

You could potentially download from source, or wait till a new version is released (within the next few days). You could also try emailing support@branch.io.